# no upload speed on one computer only

Tags: networking

Don't worry, I already tried resetting, reinstalling drivers, unplugging/replugging, and doing something I saw in other answers to this kind of issue. None of them worked. I did not look at the back side of my computer but I will soon. Pretty much my computer's upload speed is <1 mbps, while my download speed is insane (because of xfinity wifi). The internet was normal until I tried fixing a sound issue, then it began acting like so.

**UPDATE**

I looked at the Google Wifi app on my phone to check if something was wrong there because my computer is plugged in via ethernet to OnHub. I noticed that the IP address on my computer and in the app didn't match up!

Comment: Please include information on WHAT you have tried. The way your "question" is phrased the answer would be: Welp you checked everything and did everything so I guess you're just unlucky. Including a question sign would also help. Do you use the same access with another device and does it have a different upload speed? What did you try to fix your sound issue?

Comment: I have tested on different devices over wifi and possibly ethernet and they all showed normal upload speeds. The sound issue was with my headset mic, and i had some trouble reinstalling the driver, but I got the driver back and I think the issue was hardware related. That was when I noticed the upload speed issue. I searched for a solution yet everything I found didn't work.

Comment: What kind of headset are you using? What was that other thing? How did you test your upload speed?

Comment: My headset is a 2 wire analog surround sound with a mic. I am testing my speed with speedtest.net, but I also get disconnected when playing multiplayer games even though my ping is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! Turns out cofspeed's traffic shaping was causing issues. I disabled it and now uploads are fine. I probably need to calibrate cfospeed if I want to use it.